# how to make div grow right instead of down

Tags: html, css, overflow, horizontal-scrolling, expand

How can I make a div like this grow to the right instead of down? I want a constant height of my image list, and I want a scrollbar for horizontal scrolling as needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/8J2KM/

```
<div style="width:700px;height:130px;overflow-x:auto;">
<div style="height:130px;overflow:hidden;">
<a href="javascript:void();">   
    <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;color:#888;">
        <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/8.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 0px transparent;padding:9px 0px;width:130px;height:73px;" />
        <br />test1
</div>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void();">   
    <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;color:#888;">
    <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/9.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 0px transparent;padding:9px 0px;width:130px;height:73px;" />
        <br />test1
    </div>
</a>
<a href="javascript:void();">   
    <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;color:#888;">
        <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/10.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 0px transparent;padding:9px 0px;width:130px;height:73px;" />
        <br />test1
    </div>
</a>
    <a href="javascript:void();">   
        <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;color:#888;">
            <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/11.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 0px transparent;padding:9px 0px;width:130px;height:73px;" />

            <br />
            test1
        </div>
    </a>

    <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;border:solid 3px transparent;padding:3px;color:black;font-weight:bold;">
        <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/13.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 3px black;padding:3px;width:130px;height:73px;" />
        <br />
        test1
    </div>

    <a href="javascript:void();">   
        <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;color:#888;">
            <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/14.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 0px transparent;padding:9px 0px;width:130px;height:73px;" />

            <br />
            test1
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="javascript:void();">   
        <div style="width:auto;height:100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;color:#888;">
            <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/15.png" alt="test1" style="border:solid 0px transparent;padding:9px 0px;width:130px;height:73px;" />

            <br />
            test1
        </div>
    </a>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are all the styles in the HTML? Just makes it harder for yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either increase the size of the wrapping div to like 300% or how much u need or just add `white-space:nowrap` to the wrapping div and specify `overflow-x:scroll` for the inner wrapping div. You don't need `overflow:auto` in the outermost div.
So the first two divs :

```
<div style="width:700px;height:135px;white-space:nowrap">
<div style="height:135px;overflow-x:scroll;">
```

**JSFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/LnApB/

Also modify the height of these two divs to fit the height of the image+caption. 
Of course as others have already pointed out tidy up your html, put your styles to separate style sheet to improve readability and maintainability.

Comment: white-space was what I needed. The content of that scrollable div is dynamic so there is no way of knowing its width.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, lets tidy this up a little!

### HTML:

```
<div id="container"> 
   <a href="javascript:void();"> <!-- Have as many as you want. Copy -> paste. -->
   <div class="block">
      <img src="/cloudsign/web/images/layoutTemplate/15.png" alt="test1" />
      <br />test1
   </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 150px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.block {
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    color:#888;
}
img {
    border:solid 0px transparent;
    padding:9px 0px;
    width:130px;
    height:73px;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LFPYT/)

This includes a fix, take a look and work out were you went wrong. Please try to **NOT** put your CSS in with HTML. It will just make life harder for yourself, use classes `.testClass` or id's `#testID`

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep the item divs 'growing right', you need to define the `width` of the parent container to the largest width it will be inclusive of its contents (i.e. the total width of all child items).

There are a number of possible approaches,  look at **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtEYS/3/)** for options.

As an aside, **separating out your styles** so they aren't inline is recommended, aside from leading to a far increased ability to maintain and control your code, it is much more efficient.

Comment: This is working, but it is not so completely true. What if I want to have my div width of 250 px and total width of the content is 700px. With your approach the div will always occupy the full width of the available screen or the total width of all elements. What if I want to have it much smaller - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p2ann/). This is why `white-space:nowrap;` is better imo. See my answer. Anyway +1

Comment: @Fallup - see the first example in the second fiddle above. All you'd need to do is change the width of the wrapper div from 100% to whatever you wanted..

Comment: Yea didn't spot that. Anyway you still need to calculate the width of the inner div [it is easy I know, but it is unnecessary step in the process :)] to match it to total width of the elements in order to have it on "1 row". `white-space:nowrap;` is still better in this case. On the other hand the advantage of this approach is that it availables you to specify on how many "rows" the content should be, whereas in the case of `white-space:nowrap;` it is always "1 row".

Comment: @Fallup, +1, completely agree

Comment: That would be the easy solution, but the size/content of the inner div is dynamic. otherwise the obvious solution would be to set the widths correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<br/>` in your html  then it will grow horizontally.i have changed the js fiddle.Have a look.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8J2KM/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style="width:300px;overflow:auto;">

 </div>
```

put your code inside this div

i updated jsfiddle here check it.

http://jsfiddle.net/8J2KM/2/